# Nginx url rewrite error : [emerg] unexpected "}"

Tags: linux, nginx, url-rewriting, centos, directadmin

I'm trying to rewrite urls in nginx, blow is my sample code :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root   /full/server/path/to/your/cms;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /phphandler
    }

    location /phphandler {
        internal;
        # nested location to filter out static items not found
        location ~ .php$ {
            rewrite ^/([^/]*)(.*) /$1 break;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using DirectAdmin and when I add this block of code manually from linux or from DirectAdmin, I face the same error :

> nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in
>   /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/nginx.conf:178 nginx:
>   configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Notice : I'm copy pasting this peace of code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851399/nginx-clean-url-with-seo-friendly-file-names)
And I'm in doubt that the problem is where the 3 dots( ... ) are ( after `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;` ) I think there's some thing I should add here that I don't know?!
Is there anything I'm missing in this block of code?
Or there's another problem that I face this error?
Thanks in advance from anyone who helps me solve this problem :)

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of the `try_files` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you miss `;` at the end of the `try_files`.
But also this doesn't help much too.
As you mentioned you're using DirectAdmin I recommend you use `Nginx - Apache Reverse proxy`.
First of all make sure you've got **custombuild 2**

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build version
```

You should see an output similar to the following:

```
2.0.0-RC7 (rev: 863)
```

Also make sure to have version of directadmin no less than 1.45.2 otherwise the things won't work.

```
/usr/local/directadmin/directadmin v
```

Run this code to build nginx + apache with custombuild:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build update_da
./build set webserver nginx_apache
./build nginx_apache
./build rewrite_confs
```